# How to handle onItemClickListener and OnTOuchListener on the same item in GridView?

Tags: android, ontouchlistener, onitemclicklistener

First, I would like to apologize for my English. That's not my native language.

I have a simple gallery in Android. Images are loaded in `GridView`. I have problem with `onItemClickListener` and `onTouchListener`. I have set `onItemClickListener` for `GridView` and `onTouchListener` for childs of `GridView` (`ImageViews`). When I click on the image, it should be shown on the center of phone screen and when I press it, it should zoom-in on the place where my finger was and when I release my finger, it should zoom-out.

The problem is that when is set `onTouchListener`, only it is fired. I would like to recognize when I clicked and when I pressed-released.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

you are looking for checking the value of `event.getAction()` which returns `MotionEvent` constant:

```
gridView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                //Do something when user touch the screen 
                //(first touch event-before moving or releasing the finger)
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                //Do something when user release the finger touching the screen.
                break;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

You also have `ACTION_MOVE` which exist when user move his finger before he released it from the screen (good for dragging etc...)

EDIT:

The problem with `onTouch()` is that it only exist for the entire view (Your grid) and you don't have `onItemTouch()`. One solution will be to get the info you need from the item when `onItemClick()` happens into a class defined variable (For example the `Bitmap` of the picture you clicked on) and then use it to whatever you need in the `onTouch()` event. Remember in `onTouch()` if your return true at any point it means you already dealt with the touch case and `onClick()` won't happen. Also - on click calls ONLY when releasing the finger from the screen (means `MotionEvent.ACTION_UP`) so you won't have it on the touch event.

To solve this you need to either use `onItemLongClick()` instead, or set `onTouchListener` for each of the items in the grid with custom adapter (in `getView()`).

Comment: Yes, it is working, but how to fire onItemClick method? I have to implement two actions. It is similar to drop-down menu on websites - when I have mouse cursor above menu it is li:hover and then it is visible, and when I click some one option of menu, I go to site which was linked.

I would like to make some similar with android and with images.